# How to fix drag-n-drop in Teamviewer from remote Windows 8 machine to local Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, teamviewer, drag-and-drop

I am on W7 machine connected to W8 machine. Trying to drag files from W8 to local W7 machine - not working, but works the other way around.
Anyone has seen this before? Is there any fix to this?
I disable UAC on W8, problem did not go. Files can be dragged within W8 window but not outside it between computers.

Comment: That sounds normal to me. You are using remote support software. The supporter can provide files to the person you are helping, but does not mean you can take their file away. Your best method if you want to have 2-way file share is use "File Box" and then start by putting a file from W7 into the Filebox, which will open the FileBox on the W8 machine. Then you can drop files into the Filebox at the W8 side and it will be copy-able from the Filebox on the W7 side.

Comment: I agree with Darius sounds like Teamviewer is working like it should.

Comment: @Darius For me this is just the other way around (in W7->W7). When i view a remote computer i **can take** files from their desktop and drop them on my own. I **can't** drop a file from my desktop to theirs. So this is not the way you say (just the other way around :) (In the question it was not entirely clear which machine is taken over and in W7->W8 dragging of files is not possible at all). But your method with "Filebox" does work (and is answer worthy).

Comment: @Rik Interesting. My test is using TeamViewer 8, and from W8->W8, and I can drop from my PC to the client, but I can't drag out from the client into my PC. FileBox (or File Transfer, whichever is more convenient for you) is my only workaround. I don't have W7 machine to test but this is definitely interesting that the TV will act differently depends on the remote OS.

Comment: @Darius I found from this official TeamViewer [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRPYKU91Mso) it **should** work both ways. So there is something blocking it.

Comment: If your Explorer instance is running "elevated" / as an Administrator, make sure your TeamViewer instance is elevated as well. If not, make sure neither of them are running elevated.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling teamviewer worked for me.